# Printint multiple pdf pages on per page with C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, acrobat

[image]
When printing a pdf file on Adobe Acrobat, there is the ability to print multiple pages on one page. How can I do it with C#?

Comment: If you manage to print single page into bitmap, then what is left is positioning and scaling such bitmaps when printing them on a single page.

Comment: You can also try to find a PrinterDriver that provides its own PrintDialog and already has the ability.

Comment: @Sinatr I created my own printer settings interface. I put a setting here and I can convert pdf files to images (with Ghostscript). Does it make sense to fit these images on one page?

Comment: I can print my pictures between 50dpi and 450dpi.

Comment: You can check out the leadtools sdk virtual printer driver (disclaimer, i am an employee of this vendor): https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/virtual-printer/windows/dotnet/print-to-file-using-the-virtual-printer-driver.html